# how to use SCP or SFTP in the script file for file transfer

Tags: bash, sftp, scp

This script file reads the hello_world.py and source$n.vtu will be the input
data. In the end I will produce some .png files. I would like to transfer them to my local computer from the remote machine (cluster or super computer).
Can anyone tell me how to do with SCP or SFTP. Thanks!

```
low=0
high=9
mult=2
for i in $(eval echo {$low..$((high/mult))}); do
    n=$(printf '%06d' $((i*mult)))
   ./pvpython hello_world.py source$n.vtu
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a line

```
scp /path/to/file.png user@10.1.1.1:/destinationpath/
```

where 10.1.1.1 is your local machine.

I'd advise to set up a separate account for `user`, and generate a key pair to allow the cluster to transfer it passwordlessly to your local machine.